# How to switch between two sets of functions in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dependency-injection, cypress

I want to make parts of a Cypress test suite run a set of functions based on a configuration variable. I.e. version 1 of the function showMessage should be used if the version variable is 1, and version 2 if the version variable is 2. I can do it with if statements like demonstrated below. I am a JavaScript noob, but I know there are more elegant ways of doing it.

```
function showMessage(version) {
    if (version == '1') {
        console.log('Version 1');
    }
    else {
        console.log('Version 2')
    }
}

showMessage('2');
```

I would ideally like to have the functions in separate folders, each defining their own version of showMessage (without the if statement), but I am not sure how to do it properly in JavaScript.

In a way, I'm asking for an extremely lightweight dependency injection mechanism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is many many ways to do that. It is basically a decision of what is less work and is the most readable. But at the end there is never a way around for selecting what you want.
A different approach to if in each function would be:

```js
var a = {};
var b = {};

a.showMessage = () =>  { console.log('Version 1'); }
b.showMessage = () =>  { console.log('Version 2'); }

version ='1'
//set up 'reference' object c in one place, based on the selected version
c = (version == '1' ? a : b);

//Then every time we call showMessage, use the reference object (no ifs)
c.showMessage();
```

Another option would be to use the prototype of a function. That is to be said, literally the same as the above example but with the fact that it is more reuseable in some kind of way.

Comment: Initially, I did not see how this would help, because I would still have to use an If statement whenever I call the 'showMessage' function.
But then it occured to me how this could be done.
I can introduce a 'reference' object c so that whenever I call showMessage, I can write c.showMessage.
Assigning a or b to the c object only has to be done one:
c = (version == '1' ? a : b);
Would it be ok if I edit your answer to do this?

Comment: Like i explained there is no way around a if statement, atleast i think so. I mean like with assigning variables it is the same right? But i admit that it is a much better approach if functions stay the same as in the showMessage example. Ofcourse it is ok if you edit the answer :)

Comment: Indeed, one if statement is hard to get around. But one if statement is better than one if statement every time you call the function.
I will edit the code snippet then. Thanks for guiding me in a good direction!